# how can we use browse button in iphone for images or file

Tags: iphone, button

how can we use browse button in iphone for images or file.i want to upload images to server from  iphone.

Comment: It's not possible in Mobile Safari. You'll either have to write a native app, or support emailing in an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access files present in your sandbox. And on iOS, the guidelines say that you should display a list of files that can be uploaded (perhaps in a table view in a separate view), rather than a browse dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Since the iOS 6.0, the safari app and all webviews can handle upload/file html input fields for images and such.